# Grow and Fade onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a box to grow, fade, change blue , and reset according to button pressed.  So far color change , and reset are working ; fade and grow result in my box dissapearing.

How can I get the box to fade on click, while staying the same color as it currently is, and grow while remaining what color it is currently , when clicked.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>

<style> 
body  {margin:25px}
#resetDiv {height:150px;width:150px; background-color:orange;}

#blueDiv {height:150px;width:150px; background-color:blue;}

#fadeDiv {width:150px;height:150px;background-color:orange;opacity:0.75;}

#growDiv {height:150%;width:150%;background-color:orange}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="grow()">
    Grow
</button>


<button onclick="blue()">
    Blue
</button>


<button onclick="fade()">
    Fade
</button>



<button onclick="reset()">
    Reset
</button>



<div id="blueDiv">
</div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementById("blueDiv");

function blue() {
    div.setAttribute("id", "blueDiv");}

function reset() {
    div.setAttribute("id", "resetDiv");}

function fade() {
    div.setAttribute("id", "fadeDiv");}
function grow() {
      div.setAttribute("id", "growDiv")
}        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fade-in, you can add fade-in class to the element (when clicking the button).

This is the relevant css:

```
.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

For grow, you can add grow class:

```
.grow {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

So you can declare it:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv'); // get the element

function grow() { // add grow to class list
  myDiv.classList.add("grow");
}

// add fade-in and remove it after 2 seconds
// 2 sseconds are the seconds of fade-it to get completed.
function fade() {
  myDiv.classList.add("fade-in");
  setTimeout(function(){myDiv.classList.remove("fade-in");}, 2000);
}

function blue() {
    myDiv.classList.add("blue");
}

function reset() { // reset the class list
    myDiv.classList = [];
}
```

This is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/01uv92Lq/27)

Comment: changed the background-color for #fadeDiv to "currentcolor," which it now fades to a blackish grey color. how can I get it to fade while staying its current color? I have opacity at .75 and the fade was working when I had it set to background-color orange, however that was only if it was after clicking reset button.                                                                 and I tried inputting the .grow command; however I couldn't get it to work. I'm just starting in code camp so not familiar with JavaScript language.

Comment: I have it partially working you definetly helped, how do I accept your answer?   The main thing that makes this diffucult to figure out is I can only use HTML and JavaScript to get this to work, no CSS.

Comment: You didn't write that you don't want to use css.
Please remember that performance of making animation with CSS is better than making it with JS.
In order to accept my answer, you can click to vote my answer up.